# CTRL+mouse wheel in gvim (windows) not paging

Tags: windows, vim

I'm loving vim, but one thing that's bugging me is that when I hold the control key and mouse wheel up or down, the window scrolls normally when the bindings are telling it to page up/down.

I'm using the exact same vimrc file (and plugins) on one of my linux machines and the CTRL+mouse wheel does page up down (as opposed to just normally scrolling like in windows).

Is there some way to force gvim to response to a ctrl+MouseUp/Down event? It seems to be ignoring it in windows ='[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In insert mode, pressing `<Ctrl+V>`, holding `<Ctrl>`, and then scrolling with the mouse doesn't input an escape sequence, which implies that it's not possible to remap actions from the scroll wheel. Compare, for example, `<Ctrl+V>` then `<Ctrl>` with a left click, which inserts `<C-LeftMouse>`. There doesn't seem to be anything in the help about mouse events beyond the clicks either.

Comment: Thanks for the response (and the tip on escapes, didn't know you could do that). It seems like it's just broken. I'm  going to send a bug report to the gvim guys and hopefully it's a quick fix. Doesn't seem like anyone has noticed it doesn't work.